# Как сделать проверку соответствия текста кнопки с эмоджи в telegram боте?

Tags: python, telebot

Не получается сделать условие проверки текста с эмоджи для дальнейших действий.

```
menu_emoji = u'\ud83c\udf7d'

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def menu_handler(message):
    if message.text == menu_emoji+'текст': <---- *проблема тут*
```

Comment: Спасибо, но проблема не в этом. Переменная menu_emoji содержит его код. И в одной из кнопок клавиатуры текст дан с эмоджи. Надо чтобы проверка каким то образом включала в себя и наличие эмоджи.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы на `Windows 10` - нажмите `Win` + `.` и выберите соответствующий эмоджи.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def menu_handler(message):
     if message.text == '' + ' какой-то текст'
```

Answer (score -1):

Сделал по другому. Просто проверил наличие "текст" в сообщении.

if 'текст' in message.text